# Camel Aggregator completionSize vs correlationExpression?

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregate, routes

Given the following Camel Aggregator (via Spring XML):

```
<aggregate strategyRef="myggregationStrategy" completionSize="3">
    <correlationExpression> 
        <simple>${header.id} == 1</simple> 
    </correlationExpression>
    <to uri="bean:postProcessor?method=process" />
</aggregate>
```

What is the relationship between `completionSize`, `correlationExpression` and when the `myAggregationStrategy#aggregate` method gets called? Does `aggregate` get called when 3 messages have arrived at the aggregator? Does `correlationExpression` act as some sort of filter? How do they all work with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AggregationStrategy::aggregate()` is called for every exchange that matches your correlation expression. The correlation expression is used to, well, correlate incoming messages. I.e. to determine what bigger entity the incoming message is a part of. If the pieces of the bigger entity come in interspersed, then you might be assembling multiple entities in parallel and the correlation expression will keep them apart.

The completion size is one way to tell the aggregator that the bigger entity you are assembling is complete and that it should continue the aggregated exchange along the route. See chapter "About completion" on [this page](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html).

`AggregationStrategy::aggregate()` is called for every incoming message that matches your correlation expression.

Also have a look at this [example](http://camel.apache.org/aggregate-example.html).